# how get many record from an array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

I have  an array of category , and this categories have many books (belongToMany) how i can get all book

sorry about my English

category model

```
class category_b extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categoryb';
    protected $attributes = array(
        'lang'=> 'fa',
    );

  public function getBooks()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\book','categoryb_book');
  }

}
```

my book model

```
class book extends Model
{



    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\category_b','categoryb_book');
    }

}
```

my code

```
$Category = $user->subscriptions(category_b::class)->pluck('id');
$bookCategory= category_b::whereIn('id',$Category)->get();
$bookCategory = $bookCategory->getBooks;
```

Comment: try to follow the basic coding convention. Eg: your Model names should be in PascalCase.

Comment: @AnujShrestha  yes that's right , i try to use PascalCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Makdous indicated, different approaches exist, you may take the one that fits your need.

Notice that the loop approach may lead to duplicate books, so after the loop you will have to delete duplicate records.

To avoid that problem, one solution would be to query the Book model directly:

```
$categoryIds = $user->subscriptions(category_b::class)->pluck('id');

$books = book::whereHas('getCategory', function ($q) use ($categoryIds) {
    return $q->whereIn('categoryb.id', $categoryIds);
})
->get();
```

EDIT:

You may go beyond that and improve the readability of your code by defining a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

In your Book class:

```
class book extends Model 
{
    // .....
    // .....


    // Somewhere in your Book class ...

    public function scopeOfCategories($query, $categoryIds = [])
    {
        return $query->whereHas('getCategory', function ($q) use 
            ($categoryIds) {
            return $q->whereIn('categoryb.id', $categoryIds);
        });
    }

}
```

Now you can replace the old code snippet with the following:

```
$categoryIds = $user->subscriptions(category_b::class)->pluck('id');

$books = book::ofCategories($categoryIds)->get();
```

Comment: thank you bro that's work for me , and this think  is i want

Comment: You are welcome, check my updated version of the answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach` as mentioned in the [docs](http://v) to iterate through the books of you're fetched category.

```
foreach ($bookCategory as $book) {
 //access book's attributes
}
```

Or likewise you can get the categories of a certain book.

```
$book = Book::find($id);
$categories = $book->getCategory();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
 //access category's attributes
}
```

Comment: thanks for your  answer, i know that but i think may  the better way  exists

Comment: @EhSAn Well there's no better way in this, only different scenarios where you may need to use another approach to achieve what you want, for example: you can use _Eager loading_ to load the relationship, or use _DB_ class to control the query more freely.